# Export to SVF format from IDW files with an Inventor Plugin

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I've built a Inventor Addin in order to export IAM und IPT files to SVF: all works fine ;)
When I try to generate SVF from IDW files, the Inventor gives no output.

In StackOverflow I've found this topic: [Is there a posibility to export a SVF from a DWG in an InventorPlugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60072221/is-there-a-posibility-to-export-a-svf-from-a-dwg-in-an-inventorplugin)
It seems that the Inventor can't generate the SVF from drawing files.

No good news for me: I want to use my Inventor Addin with Autodesk Forge Design Automation, in order to generate SVF files both for 3D models and 2D models!

Have you ideas if Autodesk plans to add this feature in the next version of Inventor?

Have you other solutions in order to generate 2D SVF in Autodesk Forge Design Automation in a fast way, without using the Model Derivate APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Those are still your options and I'm not aware of any plans to change that.

Why do you need **f2d** files (that's what's generated for **2D** models when translating to **SVF**)? They don't seem to offer much beyond what **PDF** offers - and **PDF** is also directly supported by the **Viewer** (no translation through **Model Derivative API** is needed):
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/fast-pdf-viewingmarkup-inside-forge-viewer

Or use **Design Automation for Inventor** and **Design Automation for AutoCAD** together to get those **f2d** files.